# How to preserve references in the return type of a templated function (c++)?

Tags: c++, reference, c++20

I have a struct called TypeHolder which is basically a thin wrapper around a type T:

```
template <typename T>
struct TypeHolder {};
```

Now, I want to create a function which takes an object of any type, and casts that object to T if the object is a TypeHolder (with T being the type of TypeHolder). If not, the function should just preserve the original type of the object.

I tried to define such a function like so:

```
template <typename T>
auto castToObjIfTypeHolder(T obj, char) -> T; // This overload is called if T is not a TypeHolder
template <typename T>
auto castToObjIfTypeHolder(TypeHolder<T> obj, int) -> T; // This overload is called if T is a TypeHolder
// You call the function like so: castToObjIfTypeHolder(obj, 0), which will prefer the second overload by default (as int is a better match for 0 than char).
// However, when i called the function with an int& the return type is int but I would like it to be int& instead.
```

The overload resolution works marvellously and the right function is called each time. However, when the first overload is called, any references from the original type T are stripped away. For example, if I pass an object of type `int&`, the return type is `int`. Similarly, if I pass an object of type `int&&`, the return type is `int`.

I would like to preserve the references, ie when I pass an object of type `int&` the return type should be `int&`.

Why does the first overload strip away references and how can I preserve the references?

Comment: Use `T&&`, but then second overload might not be the best match, so you have to add constraint. `if constexpr` with `auto` might be simpler.

Comment: @Jarod42 I tried T&& but it didn't work... I just found a solution I am posting it right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to retrieve the type, you might use structure and (partial) specialization:

```
template <typename T>
struct UnderlyingTypeIfTypeHolder
{
    using type = T;
};

template <typename T>
struct UnderlyingTypeIfTypeHolder<TypeHolder<T>>
{
    using type = T;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xEavW7Mqn)

<strike>If you want to dispatch code, I would go with C++17 `if constexpr`:</strike>

```
template <typename T>
decltype(auto) castToObjIfTypeHolder(T&& obj)
{
    if constexpr (is_TypeHolder_v<std::decay_t<T>>) {
        return std::decay_t<T>::type{};
    } else {
        return std::forward<T>(obj);
    }
}
```

Note: Trait `is_TypeHolder` can be done following above method.

Comment: Your first solution does not work. When I pass T= int& , type = int. Similarly for T = int&&, then type = int... I just want to get the type and I don't really care about casting as I am working in an unevaluated context anyway...

Comment: Hard to say as you don't show your usage. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xEavW7Mqn) added BTW.

Comment: @Jarod43 Hmm... Your demo seems to work, but when I use boost::core::demangle to print out the types it gives int instead of int& (for T = int&). It seems to be a bug in boost then

Answer (score 0):

I just realised I can preserve the original type by preventing the argument from being deduced and explicitly providing the type.

Instead of calling my function like so:

`castToObjIfTypeHolder(obj, 0);`

I can do:

`castToObjIfTypeHolder<decltype(obj)>(obj, 0)`

which will preserve any references.
However this does not work with r-value references (as r-value references themselves are l-values and can't bind to r-value references), so I just need to tweak my first overload like so:

```
template <typename T>
auto castToObjIfTypeHolder(const T& obj, char) -> T;   // Now also accepts r-value references
```